# (Cordova 2.6.0 | Phonegap) Cannot call method 'exec' of undefined

Tags: java, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm having some issues with the new version of the cordova.js (2.6.0). It seems like the methods `exec` doesn't exist anymore.

```
var PhoneNumberPlugin = { 
    callNativeFunction: function (success, fail, resultType) { 
       return cordova.exec( success, fail, 
                           "com.phonenumber", 
                           "nativeAction", [resultType]);
    } 
};
```

```
ERROR: 04-18 14:47:20.039: E/Web Console(6623): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'exec' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/PhoneNumberPlugin.js:4
```

---

How could I call native plugins now? I also saw the method `callbackFromNative`! Anyone knows if this one can help me out?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that the full code for your plugin? Please see https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/wiki/Defining-Your-Cordova-Plugin-As-A-Cordova-Module I think that this should help.

Also, are you sure that you are waiting for Cordova to be fully loaded into the page? eg, wait until onDeviceReady fires.

Comment: Thats's the full code for the Javascript file. I appreciate the link, i think this should help me! :D

Comment: Just one question: this "model" can be used for Android and iOS apps?

Comment: Yes, you should use this model for both Android, iOS, and all of the other platforms, because you will only write the JavaScript API for your plugin once and in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that cordova is not defined. Make sure your cordova.js is actually being loaded and that it's loaded prior to this plugin you are creating.

Comment: Actually, it's. But I upgraded Cordova and Phonegap recently. Some how I should have done something wrong during this process :(